# Sutta with firefly simile

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, texts, simile

What is the sutta that uses the following metaphor?

> Firefly(Samsaric being) jumps into candlelight seeking a
>   pleasure(Tanha), not knowing(Avijja) that the candlelight will burn
>   the firefly to death(Samsaric Dukkha).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ud 6.9  - Adhipataka Sutta: Like Moths to the Flame

translated from the Pali by Andrew Olendzki](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.6.09.olen.html)

> “The insects are drawn irresistibly in the dark night to the shining
>   lamps, but in their zeal to approach the light they go too far and
>   only meet their doom. Humans likewise are drawn to the pleasures of
>   the senses, to what is seen and heard, not realizing the dangers
>   involved. When we get too close — when we hold on with too much
>   attachment — we get burned by suffering. The senses can still be
>   enjoyed, as the moth can stay circling the flame, but only when one
>   holds the proper distance. This quality of "stepping back" or
>   "standing off" from obsession with the senses is something that is
>   cultivated with the practice of mindfulness meditation.”

Comment: Great job finding that sutta. I was not able to find it yesterday.

Comment: When the young monks of the Mahamevnawa explain to us these sermons in Sinhala, we never think of finding the English translations. Just now I looked into the story of "Katakirilli" - of the Hawk & the Quail (Saṃyutta Nikāya 47 - The Hawk). This is another exemplary story.   https://suttacentral.net/en/sn47.6